# Undefined type 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface'

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am looking for a solution to this problem
i use php 7.4 , this error in SMTP.php in phpMailer folder
my code :

```
 //Is this a PSR-3 logger?
    if ($this->Debugoutput instanceof \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface) {
        $this->Debugoutput->debug($str);
        return;
    }
```

this error :
[Undefined type 'Psr\Log\LoggerInterface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXAWB.png)

Comment: Yes this is a PSR-3 logger interface and you solve the problem by installing psr/log package via composer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Visual Studio Code does not see your vendor folder or you dont installed the psr/log package via composer.

try to run the command

```
composer require psr/log
```

in order to get the PSR-3 Interfaces

Answer (score 0):

That should not be an error in the first place. When using `instanceOf`, the class you are checking for dos not need to exist, just as it does not need to exist in `use` statements either. For example:

```php
$a = 1;
if ($a instanceOf \Cocktails\Gin\Tonic) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
exit;
```

This will simply display false, and not generate an error even though the class it's looking for is not defined - it simply means that the `instanceOf` check will fail for a different reason.